# convert php string to json object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have a string in database that actualy is an json object. How can i convert it to see as object/array instead string? 
this is string

```
[{"id_piesa":"8","cantitate_piesa":"12","garantie_piesa":false},{"id_piesa":"30","cantitate_piesa":1,"garantie_piesa":true}]
```

Comment: Are you looking for [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_decode()` php function.

```
$json_string = '[{"id_piesa":"8","cantitate_piesa":"12","garantie_piesa":false},{"id_piesa":"30","cantitate_piesa":1,"garantie_piesa":true}]';
$array = json_decode( $json_string , TRUE);

print_r( $array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_piesa] => 8
            [cantitate_piesa] => 12
            [garantie_piesa] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_piesa] => 30
            [cantitate_piesa] => 1
            [garantie_piesa] => 1
        )

)
```

if you add TRUE as second argument the returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Here you can find the complete [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_string = '[{"id_piesa":"8","cantitate_piesa":"12","garantie_piesa":false},{"id_piesa":"30","cantitate_piesa":1,"garantie_piesa":true}]';
$php = json_decode( $json_string );

print_r( $php );
```

Have a look at this: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '[{"id_piesa":"8","cantitate_piesa":"12","garantie_piesa":false},{"id_piesa":"30","cantitate_piesa":1,"garantie_piesa":true}]';
$jsonArr = json_decode( $str ,true);
var_dump($jsonArr);
```